# SharePoint Redirect after post

Tags: sharepoint

My SharePoint input tag is using an XSLT variable for the redirect. I would like to substitute it for a javascript function to determine the value of the users input. Is this possible from within this tag? If not is possible to run a javascript function from within as XSLT variable? The following article show that something like this is possible but I need an example. http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/05/05/extending-the-dvwp-passing-xsl-variables-to-javascript-aspx/
 Thank you in advance.

```html
 <input  type="button" id="Submit" value="  Submit  " style="width:100px" onclick="javascript: if(!PreSaveItem()) return false;{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__commit;__redirect={',$RedirectLoc,'}'))}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically behind GenFireServerEvent is a __doPostBack function.

```
__doPostBack('elementgeneratedname','__redirect={' + value '}');
```

Take a look into the browser what code is generated and use it in your function. Most probably first argument is not the id of the button and is the name of the web part container (somthing like 'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$WebPartId').